# In git auto track remote branch upon checkout

Tags: git

git version 1.7.12.1

Consider a remote branch `origin/joeshmoe/ticketNumber`. In my environment when I locally create the branch (`git checkout -b joeshmoe/ticketNumber`), it will auto track to the branch on origin because the branch name matches.

I was helping a coworker and in his environment git did not auto track the remote branch.

I dug around in my settings to try to figure out why the auto track is working for me, but not working for him.  Can't seem to find anything. Does anyone know the specific setting to get this to work?

Comment: Does your coworker have multiple remotes?  If so, do more than one of those remotes have a `joeshmoe/ticketNumber` branch?

Comment: Looks like he only has 1 remote (according to ```git remote -v```)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Clarified because OP's comment indicates they misread the original.

> In my environment when I locally create the branch (git checkout -b joeshmoe/ticketNumber), it will auto track to the branch on origin because the branch name matches.

I bet what you actually typed, that caused tracking to be set up in your environment, was

```
git checkout joeshmoe/ticketNumber
```

without the `-b`.  When you *don't* tell `checkout` explicitly that it's creating a new branch, but it sees no local branch with the correct name, *then* it looks for a single remote to have a corresponding branch and (if it finds one) sets up a new branch to track that.

But if you *do* say that you're creating a new branch, that short-cut behavior isn't invoked because git thinks you're telling it that you're doing something else.  So if you told your coworker that the command is `git checkout -b <branch-name>`, then that is why git isn't setting up tracking in their environment.

This is not governed by any configuration settings as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am 99% positive I didn't miss the -b (as I do this out of instinct now that I've done it for so long). But I can check next time I am over his desk.

Comment: Well, I just ran a test to double-check, and I can guarantee if you give a `-b` it will not set up tracking.

Comment: Well, I suppose that goes back to my original question.  It does setup tracking for most of the developers on my team except for one person's environment. It should according to the documentation.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>

Comment: @MatthewKirkley - Nope. You're reading the docs wrong. **Only when you say `git checkout <branch-name>` WITHOUT the `-b` ** does the paragraph you quoted apply.  And my tests agree.  Your observations are incorrect.\